# Get the domain that requested a route in Express

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, http-headers

If I have this client-side application running on port 3000 and it request something in my API, built on top of ExpressJS, running on port 8080, how do I find out that the request was originated on `localhost:3000`?

I heard some people were using:

```
req.get('host') //or origin
req.headers.host //or origin
```

`origin` doesn't exist and host returns `localhost:8080`, the server-side. I wanted the client address.

Why is it so hard to get this information on ExpressJS?
Anyone knows how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A client-side connection just has an IP address.  It doesn't "come from" a domain.  You could do a reverse lookup on the IP address and see if it is registered in connection with a domain.  But, most clients will just report an IP address that belongs to some ISP, not a specific domain.

If you want to check if the client connection is on the same host that your server is running on (you mentioned localhost so I assume that's what you meant), then you can just compare the client IP address to your server IP address and see if they are the same.  You may need to normalize various ways that localhost could be report and you may need to make sure one isn't reporting `127.0.0.1` while the other is reporting the real IP address.

If you explain the real problem you're trying to solve, then we might be able to help you in another way.

Comment: Hello, i understand what you mean. I want to create a black and whitelist to allow and deny actions on my API. I can read the ip with req.ip and then i can make some comparisons. This info actually come with some data i dont understand, like lots of 'f' and ':'

Comment: @VictorFerreira - That's probably an ipV6 address.